# Sales for shop items

Tags: angry-birds-epic

Do items such as the rage chili, forge, or cauldron ever go on sale, or was that just a gimmick during the intro to convince people to buy coins?
In other words, if buying these items is my goal, am I better off buying them as soon as I have enough money, or can I wait for a sale?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just have to check in at the right time of day, since they're typically only on sale for an hour or two.

I managed to get all the golden upgrades when they were on sale myself, although it did take a while to gather all the coins.

Answer (score 0):

I played for several months and never saw those items on sales again.

You're certainly right, it's a trick for newbies to buy coins. :/